# Enums in kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

I want to access the `keys` for an `item` in `enum class`

```
enum class Events {
        REFER_AND_EARN {
            val key: String = "Refer and Earn"
            val source: String = "Source"
        },
        REFILL_PAST_MEDICINE_CLICK {
            val key: String = "Refill Past Medicine Click"
            val source: String = "Source"
            val pointOfInitiation: String = "Point of initiation"
        }
    }
```

Like for the above `enum class` can I access `source` like this??

`Events.REFER_AND_EARN.source`

Comment: Do you mean you  want to get all the keys of `Events`?

Comment: @Joshua keys of `Items` of `Events`.

Comment: I think Kotlin is only going to allow different methods/properties in different enum values after the [equivalent Java feature](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301) lands. Otherwise it could need to break either interoperability with Java or its own backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want to achieve by writing this:

```
enum class Events(val key: String, val source: String, val pointOfInitiation: String? = null) {
    REFER_AND_EARN(key = "Refer and Earn", source = "Source"),
    REFILL_PAST_MEDICINE_CLICK(
        key = "Refill Past Medicine Click",
        source = "Source",
        pointOfInitiation = "Point of initiation"
    )
}
```

Comment: With this solution, I have to provide a parameter for each key which will make it weirder.

Answer (score 1):

Enum constants do not declare new types themselves. This means that you can't simply access these properties: they are public, but there's no access to the type where they are declared.

You can implement an interface by enum and expose these properties by overriding ones from interface.

Or you can declare a `sealed class` instead of `enum class` and use [object declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) instead of enum constants.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use properties instead:

```
enum class Events(val key: String,
                  val source: String, 
                  val pointOfInitiation: String) {

        REFER_AND_EARN("Refer and Earn",
             "Source",
             "Unknown"),
        REFILL_PAST_MEDICINE_CLICK(
            "Refill Past Medicine Click",
            "Source",
            "Point of initiation"
        );
}
```

Or you can use a `sealed class` as others mentioned.

Comment: With this solution, I have to provide a parameter for each key which will make it weirder.